# How to configure connection timeouts for requests-based utilities?

Tags: python, python-requests, connection-timeout

Python requests [honors](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) (via [urrlib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.getproxies)) the standard `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` env variables. This is very useful when using a requests based utility: without modifying the source code, it is possible to enable / disable the proxy settings.

I would like to do something similar, but for connection timeouts. Python requests has indeed [support for timeouts](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#timeouts). But I have no way of modifying the utility that is using python requests to add timeouts to all requests calls.

Is there any environment variable which will be evaluated by requests to configure connection timeouts?